# prototype instanceof is false when extending another class

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the prototype of the current class instead of the one that it extends?

```js
class A {}

class B extends A {}

console.log(B.prototype, B.prototype instanceof B)
```

I have a loop that loops through a list of classes (see example below), I would like to check if the item is an instance of a particular class (in this case `C`). This doesn't work though because the class extends class `A`. If the class didn't extend anything, than I would get the desired results. However, it does extend another class so `instanceof ...` always comes back as `false`.

```js
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D extends A {}

[B, C, D].forEach(cls => 
  console.log(
    cls, '---',
    'Instance of C:', cls.prototype instanceof C,
    '---',
    'Instance of A:', cls.prototype instanceof A
  )
)
```

Comment: "*I would like to check if the item is an instance of a particular class*" - what does "item" refer to here? A class is not an "instance", and neither is a prototype object. Do you actually have an instance that was created with `new` somewhere, or is this question only about figuring out the relations between classes?

Comment: It's totally unclear what you mean by "*get the prototype of the current class*". If the current class is `cls`, then its prototype is `cls.prototype`, no?

Comment: "*prototype instanceof is false*" - notice that `v instanceof X` is equivalent to `X.prototype.isPrototypeOf(v)`. If you do that with `v = X.prototype`, you can be certain that the prototype object *never* inherits from itself.

Comment: No, The current class is `c`, but `c.prototype` is returning `a`

Comment: What do you mean by "it is returning a"?

Comment: if you run my second code snippet, column 2 should have 1 value that is `true` (`class C extends A {}`), and column 3 should all be `false` if that makes sense, at least that is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you run my second code snippet, column 2 should have 1 value that is `true`, and column 3 should all be `false` if that makes sense, at least that is what I am trying to achieve

I guess then you are not looking for `instanceof`, or anything to do with prototypes, but just plain simple equivalence:

```js
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D extends A {}

[B, C, D].forEach(cls => 
  console.log(
    'class', cls.name, '---',
    'is C:', cls === C,
    '---',
    'is A:', cls === A
  )
)
```

Comment: Well that works the way I want, I am not sure why but in other cases I had to use `x.prototype instance y`.

Comment: `x.prototype instanceof y` basically checks whether `x` is a subclass of `y` - certainly useful in some cases. But sure, as long as it works now, I'm happy :-)